# Dark mode adding Background Swiftui

Tags: swift, swiftui, background, background-color, uibackgroundcolor

I am trying solving problem with SwiftUI and dark mode.

I have this code for navigation button.

```
NavigationLink {
    AppInfo()
} label: {
    ZStack {
        Image("info")
             .resizable()
             .frame(width: 36, height: 36)
             .tint(.primaryColor)
    }
    .background(Color.secondaryTextColor)
    .cornerRadius(36)
    .shadow(radius: 4)
}
.position(x: 50, y: frame.size.height-50)
```

In my simulator and device is rendered correctly.

[image]

But on our customer it's added some weird background.

[image]

Do you have some idea, what is making it this way?

Comment: Have they got **Button Shapes** turned on in Accessibility?

Comment: Ouch, yes, I managed to simulate it with Button Shapes